# Two Schengen visas with a one-day gap

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a multiple-entry type C Schengen visa that expires on 30/04 and have another type C multiple-entry that starts on 2/05. So there is a one-day between the visas. I am planning to travel to Spain on 22/04 and exit on 10/05. Is this okay taking in to consideration the 1-day gap between the two visas?

Comment: which citizenship do you have? That can open other options for you. e.g. you leave  spain  for 2 days e.g.  morocco and come back to spain on 2/05.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, you need yet another Schengen C visa, single entry, for May 1st, or you need to leave on the 30th and return on the 2nd.

Failure to comply with the rules will be quite obvious for anyone who does the math. Henrik is right that nobody might bother to check the numbers, but *if* they check it, they will find that you have overstayed. That's a very bad thing to have in your file.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it: No. You're only allowed to be inside the Schengen area when you have a valid visa.

And when entering the immigration officer might request that you show intent of leaving within the validity period of your visa, so it might give you a practical problem too.

If you have a reasonable travel history and not a history of staying the maimum the 90/180-rule allows, I would probably allow it, but I'm neither a lawyer nor an immigration officer, so it really doesn't matter what I think.